# Binary Tree Custom Structure

Tags: c#, .net

I created a binary tree structure using `C#` and here's the code sample I made it work that's a custom class with methods:

```
public static class BTreePrinter
{
    static BTreePrinter()
    {
        // Static initialization code here
    }

    class NodeInfo
    {
        public TreeNode Node;
        public string Text;
        public int StartPos;
        public int Size { get { return Text.Length; } }
        public int EndPos { get { return StartPos + Size; } set { StartPos = value - Size; } }
        public NodeInfo Parent, Left, Right;
    }

    public static void Print(this TreeNode root, int topMargin = 2, int leftMargin = 2)
    {
        if (root == null) return;
        int rootTop = Console.CursorTop + topMargin;
        var last = new List<NodeInfo>();
        var next = root;
        for (int level = 0; next != null; level++)
        {
            var item = new NodeInfo { Node = next, Text = next.val?.ToString(" 0 ") };
            if (level < last.Count)
            {
                item.StartPos = last[level].EndPos + 1;
                last[level] = item;
            }
            else
            {
                item.StartPos = leftMargin;
                last.Add(item);
            }
            if (level > 0)
            {
                item.Parent = last[level - 1];
                if (next == item.Parent.Node.left)
                {
                    item.Parent.Left = item;
                    item.EndPos = Math.Max(item.EndPos, item.Parent.StartPos);
                }
                else
                {
                    item.Parent.Right = item;
                    item.StartPos = Math.Max(item.StartPos, item.Parent.EndPos);
                }
            }
            next = next.left ?? next.right;
            for (; next == null; item = item.Parent)
            {
                Print(item, rootTop + 2 * level);
                if (--level < 0) break;
                if (item == item.Parent.Left)
                {
                    item.Parent.StartPos = item.EndPos;
                    next = item.Parent.Node.right;
                }
                else
                {
                    if (item.Parent.Left == null)
                        item.Parent.EndPos = item.StartPos;
                    else
                        item.Parent.StartPos += (item.StartPos - item.Parent.EndPos) / 2;
                }
            }
        }
        Console.SetCursorPosition(0, rootTop + 2 * last.Count - 1);
    }

    private static void Print(NodeInfo item, int top)
    {
        SwapColors();
        Print(item.Text, top, item.StartPos);
        SwapColors();
        if (item.Left != null)
            PrintLink(top + 1, "┌", "┘", item.Left.StartPos + item.Left.Size / 2, item.StartPos);
        if (item.Right != null)
            PrintLink(top + 1, "└", "┐", item.EndPos - 1, item.Right.StartPos + item.Right.Size / 2);
    }

    private static void PrintLink(int top, string start, string end, int startPos, int endPos)
    {
        Print(start, top, startPos);
        Print("─", top, startPos + 1, endPos);
        Print(end, top, endPos);
    }

    private static void Print(string s, int top, int left, int right = -1)
    {
        Console.SetCursorPosition(left, top);
        if (right < 0) right = left + s.Length;
        while (Console.CursorLeft < right) Console.Write(s);
    }

    private static void SwapColors()
    {
        var color = Console.ForegroundColor;
        Console.ForegroundColor = Console.BackgroundColor;
        Console.BackgroundColor = color;
    }
}
```

The fiddle is here - [Binary Tree Structure](https://dotnetfiddle.net/aAoY8H). The code has to be copied and pasted to make it run as am unable to do that in the fiddle, but it's a running sample that you can run in your environment. I can generate the structure in the main method and was trying to generate the tree when adding nodes or elements from the array one by one in the constructor level. This is what I tried:

```
class BinaryTree
{
    public TreeNode Root;

    public BinaryTree(int?[] data)
    {
        if (data.Length == 0) return;

        var queue = new Queue<TreeNode>();
        Root = new TreeNode(data[0]);
        queue.Enqueue(Root);

        for (int i = 1; i < data.Length; i++)
        {
            TreeNode presentNode = queue.Dequeue();
            if (data[i] != null)
            {
                presentNode.left = new TreeNode(data[i]);
                queue.Enqueue(presentNode.left);
            }
            i++;
            if (i >= data.Length) break;
            if (data[i] != null)
            {
                presentNode.right = new TreeNode(data[i]);
                queue.Enqueue(presentNode.right);
            }

            BTreePrinter.Print(Root, 2, 2); //Generate the tree when adding each element from the array
        }
    }
}
```

This is the output I get: [Output](https://i.ibb.co/XjrMPd1/Screenshot-2024-01-30-185341.png)

The tree is generated each time when new element is added from the array. I tried to do some tweaks to make the tree generated once and add the elements in the same tree.

My goal is not to modify the custom class **BTreePrinter**, rather change the functionality from the constructor level of the **BinaryTree** class. Is it possible to do? Any suggestion or idea would be appreciated.

**Update 1**: Expected output a single tree with appended node from the **BinaryTree** class.

[image: Sample Output]

Comment: It seems to me that if you keep the queue and the last index at the BinaryTree class level, you should be able to continue where you left off last, adding new elements.

Comment: This code snippet `BTreePrinter.Print(Root, 2, 2); ` actually does that but am stuck for the **for loop** as it iterates and generate tree each time @500 - Internal Server Error.

Comment: Please consider your naming. [B-Tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B-tree) != binary tree. Rather a generalization that allow for more than two children per node.

Comment: It is unclear to me what you mean with "generate the tree". In the example I can only see one binary tree being created, but it is printed multiple times. If you want to make some kind of animation showing the tree being created in the console you probably need to modify the printing code. You might want to include an example of your input and desired output to make the question clearer.

Comment: Yes, the tree is printed multiple times. I don't want any animation of the tree, rather generating multiple times, can I just generate one tree from the loop in the BinaryTree class? I'll keep in mind about the naming, Thanks for suggesting @JonasH. Please check the updated post for reference.